# How can I investigate why a key ( { ) doesn't immediately respond on the keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings, mapping

I may have screwed up my Mac keyboard strokes but I have no idea how to investigate.

This issue seems to happen all over the OS and is not specific to a single application.

Some things to have in mind:

- I use Karabiner Elements to perform some simple key mappings (I changed the <kbd>Esc</kbd> to be <kbd>`</kbd> and that's all)
- I changed the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to be <kbd>Esc</kbd> through macOS preferences

Comment: What happens if you use the [keyboard viewer / accessibility keyboard](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-keyboard-viewer-on-mac-mchlp1015/mac) to test?

Answer (score 0):

The first step in investigating would be completely removing any keyboard mapping and seeing if that fixes the '{' problem. That will at least tell us if remapping your keyboard with that software is the cause of the problem.

Another step would be to try an external keyboard and see if it behaves the same way.  If not, the internal one is likely damaged.